# Why the efficiency of numpy is decreasing fastly?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question about efficiency in numpy when increasing the number of elements in a matrix/vector operation.

If you look at the example below, for a number of elements in the array of `10_000` the time length of each step is approximatively the same. Operations, 31, 32 and 33 took about 450ms. Moreover, on the last line, 36, the time length is approximatively two times the length of each individual operations which seems reasonable.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [29]: m = np.random.randn(10_000)

In [30]: shift = 1.0098765

In [31]: %timeit m - m.reshape(len(m), 1)
407 ms ± 5.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [32]: matrix = m - m.reshape(len(m), 1)

In [33]: %timeit matrix - shift
443 ms ± 6.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [34]: matrix_s = matrix - shift

In [35]: %timeit np.abs(matrix_s)
455 ms ± 3.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [36]: %timeit np.abs(matrix - shift)
936 ms ± 89.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In the following I increased the number of elements to `20_000`.

I took again a look at the time length but I do not understand the results because contrary at the case with `10_000` elements, they do not look like consistent (for me). Operation 39 is very fast compare to the following ones (10 times faster) while the length was the same previously. Moreover, operation 44 is two times longer than the sum of operation 41 and 43 where I decomposed the same calculation.

```py
In [37]: m = np.random.randn(20_000)

In [39]: %timeit m - m.reshape(len(m), 1)
1.53 s ± 47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: matrix = m - m.reshape(len(m), 1)

In [41]: %timeit matrix - shift
18.5 s ± 5.59 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [42]: matrix_s = matrix - shift

In [43]: %timeit np.abs(matrix_s)
27.3 s ± 6.65 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [44]: %timeit np.abs(matrix - shift)
1min 15s ± 4.29 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The size of the matrix is of 10^8 elements, it starts to be large but not so much I think. If I well compute it, for a size of `10_000` I have a matrix array of 763Mb, while for `20_000` it is 3Gb. Is it a swapping issue ?

Comment: I wonder if there's something internal to Python that makes allocation a 20_000 element array take longer than allocating a 10_000 array.  Your last example has to allocate two arrays per execution, and has the worst time of all.

Comment: Note also that standard deviation is also way bigger proportonally. When one would expect (it that was just the timing of millions of similar operation), that the bigger the compuation, the smaller the std in proportion (to be more precise: one should expect that stddev increases proportionally to the square root of average time, and, therefore, that ratio between std dev and average should decrease proportionally to the same square root. That time, in your case should be O(n²), since broadcasting create a n×n matrix, on which you have only linear operations)

Comment: All that to say: yes, swapping is a possible hypothesis. With swapping, cost does not increase only as O(n²), obviously, and also timing are a little bit more random.

Comment: Even if it is a little bit hasardous to say anythng about a std dev computed on 7 experiments (usually I say that timeit std dev should be just ignored. But in your case, at least if there were more than 7 experiments, they are indication that some external random things impacts more the computation time than the computation itself. For example, swapping)

Comment: "*Is it a swapping issue ?*" Yes, certainly! The timing is pretty big for this input. Note that you need 3*2=6 GiB for running timeit on the target matrix. Then, 9 GiB while running `%timeit matrix - shift` (because the matrix is already in memory and you need space for 2 temporary arrays). If you do not have significantly more memory (ie. >8 GiB), then I advise to operate on *chunks* and perform in-place operations. Note you can check the amount of swap memory so to be sure. On Linux, you can also use tools like `iotop` to see the use of your storage devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a side effect of the fact that you're using a 2-dimensional array.

When you create a 2D array using `m - m.reshape(len(m), 1)`, it will have `len(m) ** 2` elements. This means that when there are 10000 elements in `m`, it will have `10_000 ** 2 = 100_000_000` elements.

Compare this with when `len(m) == 20_000`. In this case, our 2D array will have `400_000_000` elements (4x the number of our array with 10000).

From the benchmarks you've done above, this seems to check out. The `reshape` operation takes about 3.75x as long for the 2D array.

For your later operations, things likely start slowing down due to memory speeds. Particularly, if your system is constrained on resources, this will cause problems (since it will start moving memory to the disk, making things orders of magnitude slower).

For the last operation, Python is likely using memory to store `matrix`, `matrix - shift` and `np.abs(matrix - shift)`, and I'd say that the memory required for this is leading to performance issues.